# Find the volume of the body obtained by rotating $S$ around the $x$-axis

Tags: calculus

Let $S$ be the square whose vertices are at $(0,0)$,$(-1,1)$,$(1,1)$ and $(0,2)$. Find the volume of the body obtained by rotating $S$ around the $x$-axis

I will use cylindrical method. I found shell radius is $x$ and shell height is $x+2$.

The volume is:

$$2\pi \int _{0}^{2}x\left( x+2\right) dx=\frac {40\pi} 3$$

**Can you check my answer?**

Comment: Integrating dx and rotating around the x-axis, that's the disk method, Also, x extends from -1 to 1, answer $4 \pi $

Comment: @Lozenges What's your shell radius and shell height?

Comment: Note that you can also use Pappus's Theorem, which says that the volume of a solid of revolution is the area of the slice being rotated (in this case a square) times the length of the circle travelled by the centroid (i.e., centre of mass) of that slice. The area of your square is $2$, and the centre of mass, located at $(0,1)$, travels a distance of $2\pi$. Therefore the area is $2(2\pi)=4\pi$. Even when you are required to use integration, this is a good method to to check your result. If the shape is complex, you can use this method with a simplified shape to get an approximation.